Setting font face for \mathrm in math mode
Regarding my previous question (Setting multiple language environments in LaTeX) -which is about setting different fonts for multiple language environments, I have read answers from @cfr and @Davislor and decided to try them on my lecture notes. Though, Davislor's answer is exactly what I was looking for, I still thank both of you for taking your time to answer my question.
Now on to this question, I was writing using Davislor's proposal and it looked fine, until I use \mathrm command in math mode. The text returned back to TH Sarabun Chula, which is not desired, as I want the text to be in default font. Here's the code:
%&------- This is the beginning of Davislor's proposal code, using LuaLaTeX to compile ---------&
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{english}
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=fonts ids]{thai}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{NewCM10-Regular}
\babelfont[thai]{rm}
          {TH Sarabun Chula}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
%&------- This is the end of Davislor's proposal code ---------&

\begin{document}

\textbf{ความสัมพันธ์ระหว่างพลังงานภายในและเอนทาลปีของแก๊สอุดมคติที่อุณหภูมิคงที่} 
พลังงานภายในและเอนทาลปีของระบบมีแก๊สอุดมคติมีความสัมพันธ์ ณ อุณหภูมิคงที่ จะได้ว่า
\begin{center}  $\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta n_{\mathrm{gas}} RT$
\end{center}เมื่อ $n_{\mathrm{gas}}$ แทนผลต่างจำนวนโมลของแก๊สฝั่งผลิตภัณฑ์กับฝั่งสารตั้งต้น

\end{document}


And here's the result:

The text circled in red should have been in default font. Is there any way to alter this code so I could change the roman text to the default font in math mode? I appreciate for any answers in advance. Thank you.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried replacing $n_{\mathrm{gas}}$ with $n_{\textrm{gas}}$?

Incidentally, you should really replace \begin{center}  $\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta n_{\mathrm{gas}} RT$ \end{center} with \[ \Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta n_{\mathrm{gas}} RT \].

As you've observed, \mathrm takes the "Roman" (i.e., upright) font face from the prevailing text font, not the prevailing math font. To force usage of the plain (non-bold) upright glyphs provided by the math font, the unicode-math package provides the commands \symup and \symnormal. See below for the looks of $n_{\mathrm{gas}}$ and $n_{\symup{gas}}$.
Similarly, to force usage of the bold-upright glyph provided by the math font for, say, the letter x, you should write \symbf{x} instead of \mathbf{x}.
For more information, please see section 3.1, "New commands", and especially Table 1, "New unicode-math commands which overlap with legacy math commands. For new documents the sym versions are recommended." on page 6 of the user guide of the unicode-math package.
For the use case at hand, it is true that you could write $n_{\textrm{gas}}$ to obtained the desired result. However, that's mostly a happy coincidence, and I wouldn't rely on this method too heavily.

\documentclass{article}
%\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{english}
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=fonts ids]{thai}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\babelfont{rm}{NewCM10-Regular}
\babelfont[thai]{rm}{TH Sarabun Chula}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

$n_{\mathrm{gas}}\ n_{\symup{gas}}\ n_{\textrm{gas}}$

\end{document}


You want to choose a different font for \mathrm and fontspec allows this.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, onchar=fonts ids]{english}
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=fonts ids]{thai}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{NewCM10-Regular}
%\babelfont[thai]{rm}{TH Sarabun Chula}% 
\babelfont[thai]{rm}{Tahoma}% <--- I have this one
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathrm{NewCM10-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\textbf{ความสัมพันธ์ระหว่างพลังงานภายในและเอนทาลปีของแก๊สอุดมคติที่อุณหภูมิคงที่} 
พลังงานภายในและเอนทาลปีของระบบมีแก๊สอุดมคติมีความสัมพันธ์ ณ อุณหภูมิคงที่ จะได้ว่า
\[
\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta n_{\mathrm{gas}} RT
\]
เมื่อ $n_{\mathrm{gas}}$ แทนผลต่างจำนวนโมลของแก๊สฝั่งผลิตภัณฑ์กับฝั่งสารตั้งต้น

\end{document}

For the centered formula (also called a displayed equation), don't use center.
The choice of the Thai font should be irrelevant; I used Tahoma because I don't have Sarabun Chula.

